# Chromium. "Protected content" checkbox

Tags: chromium, privacy

Today I found strange checkbox in content settings in Chromium Version 29.0.1543.0 (207211) with the following text:

> Some content services use machine identifiers to uniquely identify you
> for the purposes of authorizing access to protected content.
>
> Allow identifiers for protected content (computer restart may be
> required)

What exactly mean "uniquely identify"?
What API would be used to retrieve such an identifier?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ztd8.png

Comment: An answer to this question would most likely be in the form "This setting causes the X call of the Y API to return Z" which seems very much on-topic to me.

Answer (score -1):

Available on Windows and ChromeOS only: If enabled, Chrome provides a unique ID to plugins in order to run protected content. The value of this preference is of type boolean, and the default value is true.

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/privacy.html#property-websites-protectedContentEnabled

Comment: You linked the `protectedContentEnabled` setting, the question was about the `protectedContentEnableIdentifiers` setting.